# Do proximity or importance influence predictions by a random forest?

Tags: r, random-forest

Does proximity or importance influence in prediction quality in random forests? Or are they just information about the model? Setting them to True does increase accuracy? 
Does this model:

```
tree=randomForest(x=aa[,5:19],y=aa$rst,mtry=7,ntree=501
                  ,nodesize=6,importance=T,proximity=T)
```

make better predictions than this model?

```
tree=randomForest(x=aa[,5:19],y=aa$rst,mtry=7,ntree=501
                  ,nodesize=6,importance=F,proximity=F)
```

Comment: Small discrepancies can be expected in practice due to the different involvement of the RNG in the two cases; see the SO thread [Why does the importance parameter influences performance of Random Forest in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influences-performance-of-random-forest-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not parameters which (materially) affect the model itself, just binary flags that include extra information (the matrices of proximities and feature-importances, respectively) on the output model. Both your models will make the same prediction.

EDIT: based on the useful comment by @desertnaut.

> Although this is correct in theory, **small discrepancies can be
> expected in practice due to the different involvement of the RNG in
> the two cases**; see the SO thread [Why does the importance parameter
> influences performance of Random Forest in
> R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influences-performance-of-random-forest-in-r)

(Back to your question about what the output from `proximity` or `importance` is for: you can then try to *use* that information (esp. feature-importances) to do feature-selection and on your next iteration try to build a better model, but that's not what you meant here.

Comment: I think documentation is not clear about the calculations use. Tks!

Comment: Could not model use them to modify feature selection probability?

Comment: No, feature-selection (and feature-engineering) are topics in their own right, I suggest you read some tutorials on them. Automating feature-selection is non-trivial.

Comment: I tried to mean mtry feature probability.

Comment: ...also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956435/setting-values-for-ntree-and-mtry-for-random-forest-regression-model?rq=1 (although that also be on CrossValidated)

Comment: Although this is correct in theory, small discrepancies can be expected in practice due to the different involvement of the RNG in the two cases; see the SO thread [Why does the importance parameter influences performance of Random Forest in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influences-performance-of-random-forest-in-r)