# Why does the importance parameter influences performance of Random Forest method in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, importance

When using random forests in `R` I came across the following situation:

```r
    library(randomForest)
    set.seed(42)
    data(iris)
    rf_noImportance <- 
    randomForest(Species~., data=iris, ntree=100, importance=FALSE)
    print(table(predict(rf_noImportance), iris$Species))
```

Output:

> ```
>             setosa versicolor virginica
>  setosa         50          0         0
>  versicolor      0         47         3
>  virginica       0          3        47
> ```

and

```r
    library(randomForest)
    set.seed(42)
    data(iris)  
    rf_importance <- 
        randomForest(Species~., data=iris, ntree=100, 
                    importance=TRUE)
    print(table(predict(rf_importance), iris$Species))
```

Output:

> ```
>             setosa versicolor virginica
>  setosa         50          0         0
>  versicolor      0         47         4
>  virginica       0          3        46
> ```

In the first example I set `importance = FALSE` and in the second example `TRUE`. From my understanding this should not affect the resulting prediction. There's also no indication for that behavior in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf).

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/219498/264183) cross-validated post the importance flag should not influence the predictions, but it clearly does in the example above.

So why is the importance parameter of the `randomForest` method influencing the performance of the model?

Comment: Probably something to do with the randomness involved in random forest. I know you have set a seed but maybe the different function call alters the effect of that seed. I’d wonder if you tried a larger number of trees if you wouldn’t get the same result both times

Comment: For future reference: This questions is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63468381/11220884